# Not retrieving the value stored in the cloned text boxes using jquery and jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Script for cloning, removing and submitting the data in the text boxes to the next jsp page
SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var x = 0;
    var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

    function count()
    {
    x += 1;
    document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;
    }

    function remo()
    {
    x -=1;
    document.getElementById( "counting" ).value = x;
    }

// BUTTON for CLONING the rows :
$("button.clone").live(
        "click",
        function() {
            $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone().appendTo(
                    ".clonedOutput").attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
                    .each(function() {
                        var id = this.id || "";
                        var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                        if (match.length == 3) {
                            this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                        }
                    });
            cloneIndex++;
        });

// BUTTON for REMOVING the selected row :

$("button.remove").live("click", function() {
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
});

//BUTTON for submitting the form

$("button.submit").live("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("form1").action = "FooServlet";
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
});
```

FORM and BUTTONS :

```
<div class="clonedInput">

        <div>

            <form id="form1" method="get">
                <table>
                    <tbody id="DuplicateTable">
                        <tr id="rowToClone">
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID0" value="1" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID1" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID2" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID3" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID4" /></td>
                            <td><input id ="counting" type = "text"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="clone" onclick = "count()">Clone</button>
            <button class="remove" onclick = "remo()">Remove</button>
            <button class="submit" >Submit</button>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clonedOutput"></div>
```

code for getting data in next jsp page :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
            out.println("Id: " + request.getParameter("ID0"));
            out.println("TestCases: "+ request.getParameter("ID1"));
            out.println("DataType: "+ request.getParameter("ID2"));
            out.println("Variable: "+ request.getParameter("ID3"));
            out.println("Keywords: "+ request.getParameter("ID4")); 
            out.println("count is " + request.getParameter("counting"));
    }
```

The problem which i am facing is that, on pressing the submit button, i am getting the value stored only in the first textbox, i am not getting the values stored in the cloned textboxes.... Can somebody help me in getting the values stored in the cloned textboxes???

Answer (score 0):

Each `clonedInput` contains its own form, all with the `form1` ID. When you then submit, you're selecting the element with the `form1` ID, but since there are multiple, the browser will pick one somehow and use that. It'll then submit that one form. Not all of them. If you want to receive all of the data, pull the form up to a higher level so there's one form holding all of the inputs.

Comment: By pulling the form up to the higher levels, the clone button is even not functioning properly. The rows are not added on one click and even the data displayed on the next page is NULL for all the columns. Please can you do some editing in the above code fragment containing the form tag so that i can get the clear picture of what you are trying to say.

Comment: @user3571624: Here I'm not starting with your code fragment, but [this is what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/M8pn2/) when trying to implement my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But can you provide me the link to download the JQuery 2.x (edge) version as I am not getting that and the code that you have provided is not running on the other versions of JQuery like 1.7.2

Comment: @user3571624: [It seems to work with 1.7.2 for me](http://jsfiddle.net/M8pn2/1/), but the latest version of jQuery at the time of writing (2.1.0) is available at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js.